# Add padding in html

Tags: css, html

I have this html code which I would like align equally.

```html
<address class="address">                            
    <span>Support E-mail:&nbsp;</span><a href="#">support@gmail.com</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>Sales E-mail:&nbsp;</span><a href="#">sales@gmail.com</a>                         
</address>
```

This is the visual result that I get:

[image]

How I can place thew second e-mail always under the first?

Comment: Either give the span elements containing the field names fixed widths, or use tables.

Comment: Give a fixed width to the `<span>`

Comment: what is your CSS? - Can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: @liamness table are deprecated for layouts. use css instead.

Comment: @LelioFaieta ...unless you're using this as part of an HTML email, in which case everything is horrible and tables may be your only hope.

Comment: @PaulRoub yes, it is but this is not what the OP is saying. When I write an html formatted email I feel like coming back to 1994 so I agree with you :)

Comment: the data above could be classed as tabular data so tables should be fine for the above

Comment: @Lelio Tables are fine for tabular data, they're certainly not 'deprecated'. He has a list of fields with names and values that he wants to arrange in columns... seems pretty table-like to me.

Comment: @liamness this is not representation of tabular data. this is a plain and easy layout. Tables where used in the first layouts back in the '90s. OP request can be easily solved with css

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following styles:

```css
.address > span {
  display:inline-block; /* allows you to give a width to the span whilst keeping other inline elements on the same line */
  width: 10em;  /*width you want the span to be */
}
```

```html
<address class="address">                            
  <span>Support E-mail:&nbsp;</span><a href="#">support@gmail.com</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>Sales E-mail:&nbsp;</span><a href="#">sales@gmail.com</a>                         
</address>
```

Comment: @yak613 it just means while: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/while-and-whilst

Comment: @yak613 [only if you're from america](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/while_whilst.htm) ;)

Comment: So you're from [england](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English) or [britian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English)

Comment: and there is no such thing as a `whilst` loop. it's a `while` loop for a reason. programming is _modern_!

Comment: Yup, from Britain, most programming languages have been americanised, that's why you have stuff like color and center and loads of stuff in with z instead of s like authorized!

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78223/discussion-between-yak613-and-pete).

Answer (score 2):

```css
.sales, 
.support {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<address class="address">                            
    <span class="support">Support E-mail:&nbsp;</span><a href="#">support@gmail.com</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span class="sales">Sales E-mail:&nbsp;</span><a href="#">sales@gmail.com</a>                         
</address>
```

That is the easiest way to do it if you can use a fixed width. You can also use percentages for width if you want it to be slightly more responsive. Make sure you don't forget the in-line block as the width won't be rendered otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.service {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="service">
  Support E-mail
 </span>
  <span class="email">
  support@gmail.com
 </span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="service">
  Sales E-mail
 </span>
  <span class="email">
  sales@gmail.com
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table

```
<table>
<tr><td>Support E-mail:</td><td>support@gmail.comsales@gmail.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sales E-mail:</td><td>sales@gmail.com</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by adding a custom class and fixed width to your span classes. For example:

HTML

```
<address class="address">                            
  <span class="fixed">Support E-mail:&nbsp;</span><a href="#">support@gmail.com</a>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
  <span class="fixed">Sales E-mail:&nbsp;</span><a href="#">sales@gmail.com</a>                         
</address>
```

CSS

```
.fixed {
min-width: 150px;
border: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
}
```